# OU Search base in LDAP AD integration using CUCM

Tags: active-directory, ldap, organizational-unit

If i dont define an OU when creating user search bases in LDAP will it use the whole domain instead of a specific OU?

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: Long answer: It depends on the scope. Usually the default scope is `subtree`, but there is also `one-level` and `base`.